# Data Not updated when fetch query - React-Query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-query

I have a three-check box type,

When I check any box I call `refetch()` in `useEffect()`.
The first time, I check all boxes and that returns the expected data!

[image: UI]

but for some cases "rechange the checkboxes randomly", the returned data from API is "undefined" **although** it returns the **expected data** in *Postman*!

So I Guess should I need to provide a unique `queryKey` for every data that I want to fetch

so I provide a random value "Date.now()" but still return undefined

Code snippet

```
 type bodyQuery = {
    product_id: number;
    values: {};
  };
  const [fetch, setFetch] = useState<number>();
  const [bodyQuery, setBodyQuery] = useState<bodyQuery>({
    product_id: item.id,
    values: {},
  });

 const {
    data: updatedPrice,
    status,
    isFetching: loadingPrice,
    refetch,
  } = useQuery(
    ['getUpdatedPrice', fetch, bodyQuery],
    () => getOptionsPrice(bodyQuery),
    {
      enabled: false,
    },
  );

  console.log('@bodyQuery: ', bodyQuery);
  console.log('@status: ', status);
  console.log('@updatedPrice: ', updatedPrice);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(bodyQuery.values).length > 0) {
      refetch();
    }
  }, [bodyQuery, refetch]);



export const getOptionsPrice = async (body: object) => {
  try {
    let response = await API.post('/filter/product/price', body);
    return response.data?.detail?.price;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Why do you call refetch in the useEffect? What happens if you click on an item?

Comment: @Domino987 I call refetch just if the bodyQuery changed because without calling it in useEffect the data not fetched `status: Idle`

Comment: So if you remove the enabled: false, it will be fetched on render, if is stale or not fetched yet. and use this as key: ['getUpdatedPrice', item.id]

Comment: @Domino987 after doing what u said, the first time the query fetched once But when I click on any item 'checkbox' the data not fetched anymore

Comment: Yes you need to invaldiate it on click, so call refetch on click of the item or queryClient.invalidateQueries(['getUpdatedPrice', item.id]) to get the new data.

Comment: @Domino987 sadly It's not got the updated data :\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230445/discussion-between-domino987-and-oliver-d).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after some elaboration in the chat, this problem can be solved by leveraging the useQuery key array.

Since it behaves like the dependency array in the `useEffect` for example, everything that defines the resulted data should be inserted into it. Instead of triggering `refetch` to update the data.

Here the key could look like this: ['getUpdatedPrice', item.id, ...Object.keys(bodyQuery.values)], which will trigger a new fetch if those values change and on initial render.